# linux, filter and format grep results

Tags: linux, grep

I have a script which outputs (2 results shown here)

```
Tag: tag_453672
  Path: /abc/hosts/server42/vol/tempfile.tmp
  Server host: server42
  Region: unix
  Active: NO
  View tag uuid:00fa63f2.81f211e2.9f28.00:14:4f:9a:d2:60

Tag: tag_453672
  Path: /abc/hosts/server42/vol/tempfile.tmp
  Server host: server42
  Region: unix
  Active: NO
  View tag uuid:00fa63f2.81f211e2.9f28.00:14:4f:9a:d2:60

....
```

and I use pipe greep to filter results:

```
script | grep "Tag\|Active"
```

which produce:

```
Tag: tag_453672
  Active: NO
Tag: tag_453672
  Active: YES
```

Is there a possibility to produce each filtered result on the same line like, eventually comma delimited?

Tag: tag_453672, Active: NO

Tag: tag_453672, Active: YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
script | grep "Tag\|Active" | awk 'NR%2==1{x=$0} NR%2==0{print x, $0}'
```

Stores whenever encountering an odd line, prints when even line. Can be made less crude by using regex instead of NR conditions.

Another approach with awk

```
script | awk '/^Tag/{x=$0} /^ *Active/{print x, $0}'
```

Comment: Thanks very much, first option fits best. Thanks all of you, I cannot give points for all :(

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
./script | grep 'Tag\|Active' | perl -pe '/^Tag:/ and chomp'
```

Answer (score 1):

yass (yet another sed solution)

```
script | grep "Tag\|Active" | sed '$!N;s/\n/,/'
```

Other sed one-liners at http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/sed.html